# Rails Link_to with url and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

How do I fix this without exposing myself to a XSS attack?

```
link_to('mylinkname', '/model/slug', params[:search])
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [sanitize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) and [strip_tags](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags)